# Can I use wait() in a RESTful webservice?

Tags: java, web-services, java-threads

I have a RESTful webservice which I use for a server on NetBeans.
This webservice should get many requests from clients (multiplayer game).

I'm still new to this topic but if I understand it right- every call from clients to my webservice is a thread safe - because every connection to the web service is on a different thread (all my variables are inside the webservice methods) is this true?

And this brings me to my question:
Can I use `wait();` inside a webservice method? let's say I'm waiting for two client connections, so the second connection will use `notifyAll();`
But since the webservice is not really a thread I don't know if it's possible to use these methods there? What should I use instead??

This is my webservice:

```
@Path("/w")
public class JSONRESTService {
    String returned;

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Path("/JSONService")
    public String JSONREST(InputStream incomingData) {
        StringBuilder JSONBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(incomingData));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                JSONBuilder.append(line);
            }

            returned = "transfer was completed";

            // This is what I'm trying to add but I know that I can't:

            // count is a static variable, every new connection will increase this value     

            // only one player is connected
            if (Utility.count == 1)    
                wait (); //wait for a 2nd player to connect to this webservice

            // 2nd player is connected to this webservice
            if (Utility.count == 2)
                notifyAll ();           // notify the 1st player

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println ("Error Parsing: - ");
            returned ="error";
        }
        System.out.println ("Data Received: " + JSONBuilder.toString ());
        return (returned);
    }
}
```

**Client:**

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("string");

// Step2: Now pass JSON File Data to REST Service
try {
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/w/JSONService");
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
    OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
    out.write(jsonObject.toString());
    out.close();

   //string answer from server:
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line="";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            System.out.println("\n"+line);
    in.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("\nError while calling JSON REST Service");
    System.out.println(e);
}

br.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} } }`
```

Comment: Before multithreading. `if (Utility.count = 1)` should be `if (Utility.count == 1)`, the first one assigning 1 to count. Second point, the second `if` should be an `else if`

Comment: Thanks!  Yes I wrote it as an idea, my problem is the wait() and notify() in a webservice

Comment: Forget about code, what do you want to achieve concretely?

Comment: I need to wait for a second player (client) to connect to my web-service, then start a game (eventually I'll have to match every 2 players to play my server game). But right now the code I posted is good enough for my needs.

Comment: Wouldn't WebSockets suit you best? A REST webservice over HTTP is not what you are looking for.

Comment: You are right- but it's a project for school so I have to use webservice and know how to use it for multi-connections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use `wait()` and `notify()` as it affects the thread the code is running on. Whether or not you should use it depends on the situation.

If you want a queue of players then use a queue :)

A little example I knocked up...

```
@Path("/w")
public class JSONRESTService {

    private static BlockingQueue<Player> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(999);

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Path("/JSONService")
    public String JSONREST(InputStream incomingData) {    


        Player thisPlayer = ...; // Get player from session or something

        System.out.println (thisPlayer.getName() + " starting...");

        try {

            if (queue.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println ("waiting for an opponent");
                queue.add(thisPlayer);
                synchronized (thisPlayer) {
                    thisPlayer.wait();
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println ("get next in queue");
                Player opponent = queue.take();
                opponent.setOpponent(thisPlayer);
                thisPlayer.setOpponent(opponent);
                synchronized (opponent) {
                    opponent.notify();
                }
            }

            System.out.println (thisPlayer.getName() + " playing " + thisPlayer.getOpponent().getName());

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static class Player {

        private String name;
        private Player opponent;

        Player (String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public Player getOpponent() {
            return opponent;
        }

        public void setOpponent(Player opponent) {
            this.opponent = opponent;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks so much for your comment! I tried to do it, the problem is that the connection is lost after wait()...  My client (1st player) connects to the server, the server does "wait()- what makes My client to drop the connection ("catch"). The 2nd Client will do notify()- like in your code what will make- 1st player to continue running on the server- but the client side doesn't know about it since the connection was lost because of the wait();

Comment: I added my basic client

Comment: Hardly surprising since you have set your timeout to 5 seconds :) Can you just increase your timeouts? If not, and you want to stick with this approach, you will need to use polling - eg. keep requesting an opponent till one becomes available.

Comment: Thanks! I missed it :) I'll do both- I'll increase the timeout to 10 minutes and if it gets no answer - the client will have to click some button like "try again".  Great answer! Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Yes. All local variables inside methods are thread-safe. Class fields variables might be thread-safe or might be not. It is up to you. If rest controller has singleton scope (usually by default it has) that's mean that class fields are shared among the all requests.

So, technically you can use some shared lock object to synchonize on it. Try to do it. But it's better to do it in async mode. See Reverse Ajax Comet technique with long polling in [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-reverseajax1/index.html#long) article.

Alternatively you might use [Reverse Ajax with Websockets](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-reverseajax2/index.html) and send 'Transfer was received' back to client without any idle.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still trying to figure it out.  I'll have to use webservice because it's a project for school